# Why doesn't this process start?

Tags: vb.net, process

I'm trying to start the process Store.Client.UI.exe which is located at: "C:\Program Files\Intel\IntelAppStore\bin\Store.Client.UI.exe", or "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\IntelAppStore\bin\Store.Client.UI.exe" for 64bit like me, so I use the code:

```
    If My.Settings.instpathtype = 86 Then
        Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Intel\IntelAppStore\bin\Store.Client.UI.exe")
    Else
        Process.Start("C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\IntelAppStore\bin\Store.Client.UI.exe")
    End If
```

Where my.settings.instpathtype is whether the computer is 64 or 32 bit. But when I run it, it doesn't run Store.Client.UI.exe for some reason. When I go into Explorer and type "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\IntelAppStore\bin\Store.Client.UI.exe" it runs Store.Client.UI.exe. What's wrong?

Comment: Be aware that by default, the VB.NET & C# IDE will target 32-Bit regardless of the development machine for .exe's (as opposed to 64-Bit or "Any CPU"). This may be throwing your "instpathtype" setting calculation off. You can change this via the project settings menu.

Answer (score 5):

From the code that you posted, I don't know where/how you're getting the value for `instpathtype`, or what type it is declared as.

But regardless, you really shouldn't be doing it this way. **Hard-coding paths to the file system is a [very bad practice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/01/28/9954432.aspx) if you want your code to "Just Work."** What you posted above will not only break depending on the bitness of the OS, but also if the user has renamed or moved their Program Files folder. If my boot drive is E:, your code will fail on my computer as well.

**Instead, you should be using the special system folders.** That way, you don't even need to check whether you're running on a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system. The .NET Framework provides a really easy way of getting at these values with the [`Environment.GetFolderPath` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx), and specifying the [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) of folder you want to retrieve.

In this case, you want the 32-bit Program Files folder, regardless of the host OS's bitness, so you can use the **`ProgramFilesX86`** value to retrieve the appropriate folder, like so:

```
Process.Start(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86) & "\\Intel\\IntelAppStore\\bin\\Store.Client.UI.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are encountering problems like this, debugging comes in. Try to display what `My.Settings.instpathtype` outputs, by a simple `MessageBox` or similar. If your testing machine is 32 bit, and if the output is different from `86`, change it.

**EDIT**: So I guess you have a 64 bit machine? Try it the other way around. Swap the statements under `If` and `Else`, then put `My.Settings.instpathtype`'s output at the condition.

**EDIT**: If there are no errors on the condition, then it might be because `\` is being read as an escape character. You can fix it by adding another `\` before it.

```
If My.Settings.instpathtype = 86 Then
    Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\IntelAppStore\\bin\\Store.Client.UI.exe")
Else
    Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\IntelAppStore\\bin\\Store.Client.UI.exe")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the process is starting and then exiting immediately with an error. Use the return process from Process.Start and check some of its properties, such as proc.exitcode, proc.starttime, and proc.exittime.

```
dim proc as process
...
proc = Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\IntelAppStore\\bin\\Store.Client.UI.exe")
```